# Regex help to get a variable value from Javascript block

Tags: javascript, regex, gon

I have a JavaScript block from where I need to extract a value. it look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
window.gon={};gon.session_id="1a2b3c4d5e";gon.user={"id":"5a4b3c2d1e"}
//]]>
</script>
```

I need to get value for id. I tried with multiple options but doesn't seems to be working. E.g. `script type="text/javascript" gon.user.id="(.+?)"`

PS: **gon** is gem used to pass dynamic variables in Javascript block.

Comment: This might sound like a stupid question but why can't you use `gon.session_id` directly? Are you not using the ID in the JS code directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex will be

```
/"id":"(\d*\w*)"/i
```

The above pattern will search for the value in "id":"5a4b3c2d1e" pattern and will return 5a4b3c2d1e.

https://regex101.com/ is an awesome site to play around with Regex.

Comment: Thanks mate. it worked and it's an awesome site to check.